# Getting user's liked pages using the facebook api in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I want to extract all of my liked pages (name, category, page id). I am at that point when it returns me a json with the last  100 liked pages and also it returns me a kind of pagination ( like [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging)). My problem is that I don't want a pagination I need all of my liked pages, once. I want to put all of this in a db. This is what I achieved:

```
//.....
//login part
//.....
$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/likes?limit=100' ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
echo "<pre>"; print_r($user_profile); echo "</pre>";
```

How can I put my  all of my liked pages into one array ?

Comment: You can not get unlimited amounts of data in one request. The `limit` parameter has different max values for different endpoints – and if there’s more results than that, then you _have to_ use pagination.

Comment: To add all of data in db you have to develop an interface for pagination and after that you have to click each time on the next button to insert the data into db, which is inacceptable for me, as @luschn suggested, you can use recursitivity.

Comment: Someone please explain me, why my post is voted down? for me it is a fair question, but who knows . I want to ask better question next ime.

Comment: You don’t have to develop an “interface”, you just have to use the pagination mechanism _of the API_. Of course that does not exclude doing it recursively. (Although you might run into execution time problems with that at some point.)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the limit, but afaik there is a max amount and it is very unreliable. You can never be sure to get all likes, the only really reliable way is to implement paging. For example, you can use a recursive function to get all entries with paging. If you don´t know what i mean, google for "recursive function php" (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

As luschn suggested I user recursivity:

```
$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/likes?limit=100' ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
$user_array =  $user_profile->asArray(); 
require_once __DIR__ . "/fb/demo/Fb.php";
$fb = new Fb();     $fb->get_liked_pages(json_decode(file_get_contents($user_array['paging']->next)));
```

This is the class fb content:

```
class Fb{

        public function get_liked_pages($next){


            if (!empty($next->paging->next)){
                $params = json_decode(file_get_contents($next->paging->next));
                //here you can implement a script for adding data in db
                return $this->get_liked_pages($params);
            }
        }
    }
```